# I need to print the values from a checkbox to the page in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I need the checkbox values to print on to the page when the submit button is pressed. As I have it now it will only print one value from the checkbox no matter how many are checked. The checkbox is the region.

I'm not sure where to go from here, so any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkform () {
info = document.getElementById("personalInfo");
    info.innerHTML = "<strong>Peronal Info: </strong>" + "<br>" + "Name: " + 
                    document.feedback.fname.value +
                    " " +
                    document.feedback.lname.value +
                    "<br>" + "Email: " +
                    document.feedback.email.value;

    info = document.getElementById("experienceSubmit");

    var compensationValue,regionValue;
    //Get compensation value
    for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.comp.length;i++){
        if(document.feedback.comp[i].checked){
        compensationValue = document.feedback.comp[i].value;
    }
}
    //Get region value
    for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.region.length;i++){
        if(document.feedback.region[i].checked){
        regionValue = document.feedback.region[i].value;        
    }
}


info = document.getElementById("otherSubmit");
    info.innerHTML = "<strong>Other information: </strong>" + "<br>" + "# of References " + 
                    document.feedback.reference.value +
                    "<br>" + "Additional Comments: " +
                    document.feedback.comments.value; 
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body background="../Assignment 5/_images/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" >
<form   name="feedback" method="post" onSubmit="return checkform()">
        <section  id="pinfo" class="inputArea">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name: </td>
                    <td><input name="lname"
                               type="text"
                               autofocus
                               required
                               placeholder="lname"                               
                               size="25" />
                    </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: </td>
                    <td><input name="fname"
                               type="text"
                               size="25"
                               required
                               placeholder="fname" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email: </td>
                    <td><input name="email"
                               type="email"
                               size="40"
                               required
                               placeholder="....@hotmail.com" />
                     </td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Gender: </td>
                    <td><select name="gender">
                            <option selected disabled style='display:none;'>
                            Gender</option>                         
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>                      
                        </select>

                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
</section>
<section id="experience">
            <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <label for="experience">Years of Experience: </label>
                    <input name="experience" type="number" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="date">Date</label>
                        <input name="date" type="date" />
                    </td>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="comp">Compensation: </label><br>
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="Salary" value="Salary Selected">Salary &nbsp;
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="SalaryWB" value="Salary with bonus Selected">Salary with Bonus &nbsp;
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="Commission" value="Commission Selected">Commission &nbsp;
                    </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="region">Region: </label><br>
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="East" value="East Selected">East &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="West" value="West Selected">West &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="North" value="North Selected">North &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="South" value="South Selected">South &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          </fieldset>
</section>
<section id="other">
<fieldset>
          <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <label for="reference">References<br>0&nbsp;&nbsp 1 &nbsp;&nbsp 2 &nbsp&nbsp 3 &nbsp&nbsp 4 &nbsp&nbsp 5<br></label>
            <input name="reference" id="reference"
                    type="range" 
                    value="0"
                    min="0"
                    max="5"
                    step="1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="comments">Additional Comments: <br></label>
                    <textarea 
                    name="comments"
                    rows="5" 
                    cols="20" 
                    placeholder="Please include any other pertinent information here"></textarea>                   </td>
            </tr>          
          </table>          
</fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</section>
</form>
<section id="personalInfo"></section>
<section id="experienceSubmit"></section>
<section id="otherSubmit"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: you have not displayed the entire function..

Comment: you have not displayed entire function plus why don't you use radio button instead of checkboxes if you want want one of them to be selected?

Comment: I want as many as the user wants selected.

Comment: then why do you want to display only one? doesn't make sense in case you wan't one @kyle's answer is best otherwise i suggest you use radio buttons with same name that will return you a single value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.region.length;i++){
    if(document.feedback.region[i].checked){
    regionValue = document.feedback.region[i].value;        
}
```

is wrong. You set the regionValue every time you find a checkbox that's checked, instead of appending to it. Try

```
    if (regionValue == '') {
        regionValue = document.feedback.region[i].value
    } else {
        regionValue = regionValue+','+document.feedback.region[i].value
    }
```

Comment: This gives me the last box checked and says undefined before that.

Comment: Sorry, i overlooked that you didn't initialze regionValue. Put regionValue="" in front of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you would need to grab all of the checkboxes and add their contents to the form/div/wherever you want to place them.  Inside of your form submit function, you could add:

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myform'), //Your form
    inputs = myform.getElementsByTagName('input'), //The inputs in the form
    regionsContainer = document.getElementById('regions'), //The place to put the regions
    regions = [], //Temporary array to store our values
    i, l;
//Loop through the inputs
for(i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
    //Make sure it is a checkbox, it's name is region, and it is checked
    if(inputs[i].type === 'checkbox' && inputs[i].name === 'region' && inputs[i].checked) {
        //Add the value
        regions.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
//Display our regions
regionsContainer.innerHTML = regions.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thanks guys.

```
var compensationValue,eastValue, westValue, northValue, southValue;
        //Get compensation value
        for(var i=0;i<document.feedback.comp.length;i++){
            if(document.feedback.comp[i].checked){
            compensationValue = document.feedback.comp[i].value;
        }
    }
        //Get region value
        eastValue=""; westValue=""; northValue=""; southValue="";
        if (document.feedback.east.checked) {
        eastValue = document.feedback.east.value;
        }
        if (document.feedback.west.checked) {
        westValue = document.feedback.west.value;
        }
        if (document.feedback.north.checked) {
        northValue = document.feedback.north.value;
        }
        if (document.feedback.south.checked) {
        southValue = document.feedback.south.value;
        }
```